# How to follow a hyper-refernce in scrapy if the href attribute contains a hash symbol

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

In my web-scraping project I have to scrape the football matches data from https://www.national-football-teams.com/country/67/2018/France.html
In order to navigate to matches data from the above url I have to follow a hyper-reference that has a hash in the url:

```
<a href="#matches" data-toggle="tab">Matches</a>event
```

The standard scrapy mechanism of following the links:

```
  href = response.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'matches')]/@href").extract_first()
  href = response.urljoin(href)
```

will produce a link that will not lead to the matches data:
https://www.national-football-teams.com/matches.html

I would appreciate any help. Since I am noobie to web-scraping and anything which has something to do with web-development, a more specific advice and/or a minimal working example is highly acknowledged.
For the completeness here is the complete code of my scrapy-spider:

```
import scrapy

class NationalFootballTeams(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "nft"

    start_urls = ['https://www.national-football-teams.com/continent/1/Europe.html']

    def parse(self, response):

        for country in response.xpath("//div[@class='row country-teams']/div[1]/ul/li/a"):
            cntry = country.xpath("text()").extract_first().strip()

            if cntry == 'France':
               href = country.xpath("@href").extract_first()

               yield response.follow(href, self.parse_country)


    def parse_country(self, response):
       href = response.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'matches')]/@href").extract_first()
       href = response.urljoin(href)
       print href
       yield scrapy.Request(url=href, callback=self.parse_matches)

    def parse_matches(self, response):
        print response.xpath("//tr[@class='win']").extract()
```

Answer (score 0):

When clicking that link, no new page or even new data is loaded, it's already in the html, but hidden. Clicking that link will call some javascript that hides the current tab and shows the new tab. So to get to the data, you don't need to follow any link, but just use a different xpath query. The match data is in the xpath `//div[@id='matches']`.